# Scala in VSCode: error highlighting not working

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, lint

I want to use VSCode to work on Scala code, but cannot get error highlighting to work.
See some example code below, how it looks like, vs. how I want it to highlight errors.

[image: How it looks like in VsCode with Scala Metals Extension installed]

[image]

I think every proper programming language should have code editor support for highlighting of obvious errors regarding undefined variables, functions or operator overloadings.

What can I do, to get error highlighting for Scala in VSCode?

Comment: Use Scala Metals and check with Doctor if your setup is correct: https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode#run-doctor . Then errors will be shown after compilation https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/#diagnostics .

Comment: Okay, thanks, I figured, somehow my VSCode did not compile the files in the background. Using sbt ~compile in a terminal fixed the issue.